# Datatables buttons extension not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been researching this for a while and I can't figure out why this isn't working. It was working at one point but my table wasn't styled right, I was missing one of the datatables files and after that it stopped working. I've tried removing and adding different js and css links, tried different orders and tried different ways of coding the tables script itself. Any ideas?

Here are my js/css

```
{% block stylesheets %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

    {% endblock %}
    {% block javascripts %}

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.24/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And for the table

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    ddom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
                    ]
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: Are you including the buttons CSS file?

Comment: I might have deleted it when playing around with them but I added it and it's still not working

Comment: I think maybe the buttons are named wrong, as a test, throw in `print` as one of them.

Comment: I tried another one that just has `new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf',`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                ddom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

to

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                -------->dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

You have an extra "d" just remove it

Comment: That worked, thanks. Originally I had it when I clicked on the PDF it just opened, now it asks me to save it then manually open it. Is there a way to have it just open?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before, but my solution was to append the buttons to an element outside the table that I knew existed.

```
myTable.buttons().container().appendTo($('#print'));
```

And my table was made like this...

```
myTable = $('table').DataTable({...
```